# Array element number

Tags: c++, arrays

I need some help with a simple program. And no - its not my homework (I am learning Cpp for myself and maybe use it in future)
So yeah. I have a program, that reads arrays size `10`, and then put numbers in it `{2.56, 1.598, 0, 5.15, 0, 3.012, 10, 4.789, 2.569, 0}`
The program should ignore the `0`, and it does, but the problem is.. I need to get the number of the where the number is placed in array
(Smallest number is `1.598` and its `2` in the array)
Meanwhile I get number `8` on the biggest (should be `5` if zeros would be ignored)
and `1` on the smallest. How can I fix that ?
Heres the void of the biggest number :

```
void Biggest(float array[], int n, float &max, int &maxNr)
{
    max = array[0]
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        if (array[i] == 0)
            continue;
        if (array[i] > max){
            max = array[i];
            maxNr = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Printing void :

```
void Print(float min, float max, double avg, int maxNr, int minNr)
{
    ofstream info;
    info.open("result1.txt");
    info << "Biggest: " << max << "  Number : " << maxNr << endl;
    info << "Smallest: " << min << "  Number : " << minNr << endl;
    info << "Average: " << avg << endl;
    info.close();
}
```

And all main.

```
int main(){
    float array[100];
    int n;
    float max;
    float min;
    double avg;
    int maxNr, minNr;

    Reading(array, n);
    Biggest(array, n, max, maxNr);
    Smallest(array, n, min, minNr);
    Average(array, n, avg);
    Printing(min, max, avg, maxNr, minNr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. You're missing a `;` at the end of `max = array[0]`, and you have unmatched `{` in `Biggest()`.

Comment: Try editing your post to include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Unclear what you want, but `std::minmax_element` might help.

Comment: It does compile. I deleted it, I guess. (new to stackoverflow, so had some problems with putting code in) 
Heres native lang, original, pastebin http://pastebin.com/zRpGLe0D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, array indexes start at `0`, not `1`.

If you want to get the position ignoreing zeros, you need to use a separate counter variable from the one used to index the array, so that you don't increment it when you skip over `0`.

```
void Biggest(float array[], int n, float &max, int &maxNr)
{
    max = array[0];
    int position = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (array[i] == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        if (array[i] > max){
            max = array[i];
        }
        position++;
    }
    maxNr = position;
}
```

Comment: If you store `max` as `array[0]`, you might begin your loop with `1`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Good point. But then this requires some extra checking in case `array[0]` contains `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in most (all that I can think of) programming languages start at index zero. So simply change your for loop condition to be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Because you want the loop to start at the first element in the array, i must be initialized to 0. That should fix the problem you are having with the array.

Comment: He's skipping 0 because he initializes `max = array[0];`